# How do i get referer from chrome extension webRequest api?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

I'm trying to get complete **referer** from chrome extension's **webRequest api**. This is how my function looks like. I need to find alternative to `details.initiator`, as it's not enough precise.

```
//Listner to the onBeforeRequest event from webRequests api 
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {

        //Checks if details url contains pixel.domain.com substring
        if (details.url.toLowerCase().indexOf('pixel.domain.com') > 0) {

            //Checks if map already contains array for this initiator
            if (pixels.get(details.initiator)) {
                var urls = pixels.get(details.initiator);
                if (!urls.includes(details.url)) {
                    pixels.set(details.initiator, [...urls, details.url]);
                }
            } else {
                //Else sets new (key, value)
                pixels.set(details.initiator, [details.url]);
            }
        }
    },
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'] }
);
```

**Update:** It can be also alternative to webRequest api, as i just need something, what tracks all requests made by the browser. Was considering also onRequest, but i'm not sure if it's not deprecated.

Comment: @wOxxOm I found other solution. Instead `onBeforeRequest` i use `onBeforeSendHeaders`, where i have access to the request headers.

Comment: That's a good solution, consider adding an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead `onBeforeRequest`, I use `onBeforeSendHeaders`, where I have access to the request headers